# radgridview jump

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I have this xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFExample"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<Window.Resources>
    <x:ArrayExtension Type="{x:Type local:Model}" x:Key="Models">
        <local:Model StringProp="Some value" Int32Prop="3" />
        <local:Model StringProp="Another one" Int32Prop="12" />
        <local:Model StringProp="The same" Int32Prop="132" />
        <local:Model StringProp="Tired..." Int32Prop="-5" />
        <local:Model StringProp="End it" Int32Prop="43" />
        <local:Model StringProp="..." Int32Prop="11" />
        <local:Model StringProp="the end." Int32Prop="12" />
    </x:ArrayExtension>
</Window.Resources>
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <telerik:RadGridView  x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Models}">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewColumn >
                    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="200">
                                <ComboBox.Items>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                </ComboBox.Items>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn>
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>

        <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grid1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Models}">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="200">
                                <ComboBox.Items>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                </ComboBox.Items>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>

        <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grid2" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Models}">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="200">
                                <ComboBox.Items>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
                                </ComboBox.Items>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

It's just simple window with three radgridviews, all of a kind.

Problem: if one of radgridviews not entirely visible and i click on combobox within this radgridview, then it first jumps into view, and just then combobox click processed. How can i remove this behaviour, coz i don't need radgridview to be fully visible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now i use this workaround

```
private void RadGridView_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```